# Possible to Draw Custom Routes on MKMapKit ? (iOS)

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I know that it is possible to add annotations to an iOS Map.

Is it possible to draw a custom path (such as a path cutting through a park) on my MKMapView and then create a route on the MKMapView using that custom path?

Comment: I suggest starting [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW15) and using [MKPolyline](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolyline_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKPolyline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add MKCircle overlay
2. In viewForOverlay: create a bezierPath (CG or UI) and add it to the path property of a standard MKOverlayPathView instance

go through this to understand in detail

http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=65

hope it helps. happy coding :)